# psychotherapy video session

Tags: data-request, video

I am looking for real video sessions of psychotherapy on real people, and not just video lectures with theoretical material.That is, a video case study of work with various problems (depression, phobia, PTSD, anxiety, loss of loved ones, and so on).
Are there any such sessions in the public domain?